# Trouble setting up Daemon mode with Apache/Django in Centos when I am not using a virtual environement

Tags: python, linux, django, apache

I am currently attempting to set up apache on my centos system with django. So far I have followed all of the instructions on the docs and everything works well. 
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)
Unfortunately when I try to replace the WSGIPythonPath command with

> WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-> path=/path/to/mysite.com:/path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   WSGIProcessGroup example.com

as reccomended, I run into a road block. I am not using a virtual-environment for this project. I tried not having anything after the : and I also tried linking to the python2.7 site packages on my machine, both resulted in me being told there was an error on the line with daemon process. When I revert back to WSGIPythonPath my apache runs fine.

What should I do?

Comment: What happens if you try it without the `python_path` parameter altogether?

Comment: What is the 'road block'? Properly explain what the error is that you are getting. Also go read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/python-module-search-path-and-modwsgi.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html You are better off using ``python-home`` rather than ``python-path`` to specify the location of the Python virtual environment.